# Iterate through array in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
const cal_days =['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
const cal_months =['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April',
 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
const daysinmonth =[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
const curr =new Date();
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
var yearName=d.getFullYear();
var monName= cal_months[n];
var firstDay = new Date(yearName,n, 1);
var startD = firstDay.getDay();
var num= daysinmonth[n];
var day=1;

class Show extends Component{
 numrow(){ 
  var array=[];
  for (var i = 1; i <=num; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { 
    if (day <= num && (i > 0 || j >= startD)) {
      array.push(i);
      day++;
      }
      if (day > n)
        break;
       }
      }
 array.map(function(){
 for (var i = 1; i <=6; i++) { 
  // console.log(<td>{array[i]}</td>);
  return <td>{array[i]}</td>;
 }
 })
 }
 render(){
 var daysname= cal_days.map(function(day){
 for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ){
  return <td>{day}</td>;}
 })
 return (
 <div>
 <table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 {daysname}
 </tr>
 <tr>
 {this.numrow()}
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 ) 
  }
  };
```

---

I have started studying Reactjs. I am making this calendar in Reactjs. I want to display the days 1,2,3..so on. Why does the function numrow doesn't display anything? I haven't posted the whole code here, just a part of it. Have I used array.map() function correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the [map api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and how to use this function.
your array.map should be something like this:

```
array.map(function(val){
  return <td>{val}</td>;
})
cal_days.map(function(day){
  return <td>{day}</td>;
})
```

The `for loop` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is printed because you didn't return anything from the function numrow. I have did some modification in your logic to print what you want.

```
class Show extends Component {
numrow() {
    var array = [];
    do{
        var arrayRow = [];
        for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
            if (day <= num && (j >= startD || day >= startD)) {
                arrayRow.push(day);
                day++;
            } else {
                arrayRow.push("");
            }
        }
        array.push(arrayRow);
    }while(day < num)

    return array.map(function (arrayRow) {
        return (
            <tr>
                {arrayRow.map(function(item){
                    return <td> {item} < /td>        
                })}
            </tr>
        )

    })
}
render() {
    var daysname = cal_days.map(function (day) {
           return <td > {day} < /td>;
    })
    return ( 
        < div >
            < table >
                < tbody >
                    < tr > {daysname} < /tr> 
                    {this.numrow()} 
                < /tbody>
            < /table>
        </div>
    )
}
};
```

Comment: This will print space until day becomes >=6. So 1 comes on Saturday so does 2,3,4,5. And then they will start printing from Monday (from 6).

Comment: @sugandh you have asked why your function numrow doesn't print anything and the reason is you ditn't return anything from the function and by default it returns the undefined. what you wants to print its your logic